# How to compare FTPClient File's last modification with a local file?

Tags: java, file-io, apache-commons, ftp-client, last-modified

I have two files one in the server and one is local, I want to get the last modification of both files and see which one is newer. I made a method, but I always get the same result. I tried the test each side, but the if statement make the same decition always.

Here is my code:

```
public void SyncCheck(FTPClient ftpClient, String remoteFilePath, String savePath) throws IOException, ParseException{
        String time = ftpClient.getModificationTime(remoteFilePath);
        Date remoteFileDate = timeSplitter(time);
        Date LocalFileDate = new Date(new File(savePath).lastModified());

        if(remoteFileDate.after(LocalFileDate)){
            System.out.println("Remote File is newer: " + remoteFileDate);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("nothing");
            System.out.println("Remote " + remoteFileDate);
            System.out.println("Local " + LocalFileDate);
        }
    }

    public Date timeSplitter(String time) throws ParseException{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        String timePart = time.split(" ")[1];
        Date modificationTime = dateFormat.parse(timePart);
        return modificationTime;
}
```

The result is always this:

```
nothing
Remote Fri Apr 03 02:20:30 BST 2015
Local Fri Apr 03 03:12:58 BST 2015
```

No matter is the remote file is newer or older. The other this I notices is that the remote file is modified at 03:20:30, but it is one hour behind always. Is is about anything with time zones?

Or any idea to compare last modification time of one server file vs. a local one ?

Comment: Do you always get the same modificationTime? What is the problem?

Comment: @Paner No the modification time changes if I modify the file, but the problem is the server file is one hour behind always. so if I modify it now, it gives the time of an hour ago. So it is always older than the file in the local time. And this is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way to know ftp server timezone, but what you can do is to upload a file and then calculate the time difference between the file time reported by FTP and locally. This must be a method running as a first step of your program to initialize the timezone logic in every client application of yours.

Comment: Thanks. I achieved the same idea after my research.